# if condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

am trying to perform an if condition in javascript, but i cannot get the output. i tried the code below:

```js
function myfunc(size){ 
   
   
    var m = parseInt(size);
    var size2 = (m).toString();
  if(m <= 2){
    sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 1 node will be required for processing');
    
    }
  if(m > 2 || <= 4){
    sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 3 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }

  if(m > 4 || <= 6){
    sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 5 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }
  if(m > 6 || <= 8){
    sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 7 nodes will be required for processing' );
    
    }
  if(m > 8){
    sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 11 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }


   
   
  }
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Try this if(m > 2 && m <= 4) with m <= 4 and also in all the other cases. You have to use the var again

Comment: @Sanaya, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @funky thanks a lot, it actually works :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "&&" instead of "||" in your 'if' conditions, and also correct your syntax. You have to do if(m>2 && m<=4).

The OR condition ( || ) means that that condition will execute IF the value of m is greater than 2 OR less than 4. Now 1 is also less than 4, so it can execute for 1 as well.

If you write '&&' instead, it will mean that it should ONLY execute if m is greater than 2 AND less than or equal to 4.

Comment: Worth noting that since the conditions are mutually exclusive, you're best off doing `if(m<=2) ... else if(m<=4) ... else if...`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly implementing the if condition with || operator. You should do it like eg : `if(m > 2 ||m<= 4)`

```js
function myfunc(size){ 
   
   
    var m = parseInt(size);
    var size2 = (m).toString();
  if(m <= 2){
    alert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 1 node will be required for processing');
    
    }
  if(m > 2 ||m<= 4){
    alert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 3 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }

  if(m > 4 || m<= 6){
    alert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 5 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }
  if(m > 6 || m<= 8){
    alert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 7 nodes will be required for processing' );
    
    }
  if(m > 8){
    alert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 11 nodes will be required for processing');
    
    }
 
   
  }
    
    myfunc("5")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that comparisons after || do not have a second operand.
Changes (Notice **|| m**)

- `if(m > 2 || <= 4)` to `if(m > 2 || m <= 4)`
- `if(m > 4 || <= 6)` to `if(m > 4 || m <= 6)`
- `if(m > 6 || <= 8)` to `if(m > 6 || m <= 8)`

Changes applied

```
function myfunc(size){ 
        var m = parseInt(size);
        var size2 = (m).toString();
        if(m <= 2){
                sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 1 node will be required for processing');
                }
        if(m > 2 || m <= 4){
                sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 3 nodes will be required for processing');

                }
        if(m > 4 || m <= 6){
                sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 5 nodes will be required for processing');

                }
        if(m > 6 || m <= 8){
                sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 7 nodes will be required for processing' );    
                }
        if(m > 8){
                sweetAlert('dataset file is: '+size2 + 'a cluster of 11 nodes will be required for processing');    
                }
        }
```